# ConEmu: create text that links to URLs

Tags: conemu

I'm trying to find out if it's possible in ConEmu to make clickable non-URL like text, that links to an URL. Just like on webpages.

I found [this page](https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda) about a bunch of terminal emulators and multiplexers which already support it, but ConEmu isn't in the list. I would rather not switch to any of them, because I'm so used to ConEmu.

So, does ConEmu have this functionality? Can ConEmu support writing your own custom functionality so it's able to support this?

Answer (score 1):

ConEmu can detect and highlight hyperlinks when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed.

When underlined in this way, a hyperlink will open with a left-click.

See in the ConEmu help :
[The detector](https://conemu.github.io/en/FileLineDetector.html).

[image]

Comment: I'm aware ConEmu can detect links to webpages and files. I'm wondering if it's possible to create text that links to a URL, by some hidden markup. For example, in my terminal I have the word 'foo' with special markup, that then links to www.google.com. There is more information in de link that I provided, about other terminal multiplexers that already support such a markup.

Comment: These utilities are from Linux where the consoles are more developed. In ConEmu I haven't found such a feature or even a plugin.